# Can't enumerate an F# list of lists in C#

Tags: c#, exception, f#

In the F# code below I have a module with two values defined: an `int list` and an `(int list) list`.

In the C# code below that I have unit tests that attempt to iterate the list values defined in F#.

When I run the unit tests I get the following output.

> `[1; 2; 3] 3 1 2 3`
>
> `[[1; 2; 3]; [2; 3; 4]] Test`
>   `'MasterMind.Test.ConsistentCodeTests.CanIIterateListsOfLists'` failed:
>   `System.EntryPointNotFoundException` : Entry point was not found.
>   at `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1.GetEnumerator()`
>   at `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source)`
>     `ConsistentCodeTests.cs(49,0)`:
>   at `MasterMind.Test.ConsistentCodeTests.CanIIterateListsOfLists()`
>
> 1 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 3.11 seconds (NUnit 2.6.4).

Accessing the `int list` works fine. The C# code can successfully print it, get its count, and iterate it.

Trying to get the count of or iterate the values of the `(int list) list` value throws an `EntryPointNotFoundException`. I do not know what to do to fix this error.

```ml
module Game.Engine
  let aList = [1;2;3]
  let listOfLists = [[1;2;3];[2;3;4]]
```

```cs
[Test] public void CanIIterateAList()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Game.Engine.aList);
    Console.WriteLine(Game.Engine.aList.Count());
    foreach (int i in Game.Engine.aList) Console.WriteLine(i);
}

[Test] public void CanIIterateListsOfLists()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Game.Engine.listOfLists);
    Console.WriteLine(Game.Engine.listOfLists.Count());
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke the test runner?

Comment: It's very strange, it should work. You should get 2 without any trouble.

Comment: I've checked it in F# interactive, it works:
`open System.Linq;; let a = [[1;2;3];[2;3;4]];; let b = a.Count();;` b = 2.

Comment: In a plain console program, the code you posted works perfectly fine for me. I don't see why you'd get a different result in your unit test environment, but you need to improve this question so that the problem is reproducible, i.e. with a [mcve]. Either explain in detail how to configure an appropriate unit test harness that will reproduce the problem, or provide a good standalone console program example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like an `FSharp.Core` version mismatch. Check that one of your packages hasn't installed the `FSharp.Core` v3.something - if it has, update to the newest stable package.

If that isn't enough, in the app.config for your test project (assuming that your test runner will pay attention to it) check that there's a binding redirect to the correct v4 assembly.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

If that still doesn't help, delete the `obj` folder under your test project and rebuild.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thanks